# Register Decorator in Simple injector, common interface

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, decorator, simple-injector

I have a problem with a IoC with Simple Injector for Decorator..

How to register it in the Ioc Simple injector ?

```
var data = new Data();
var test = new Data2Decorator (data,
    new Data1Decorator(data, new XxxData(data)))
```

I tried it this way.

```
_container.Register<Ixxx1>();
_container.Register<Ixxx2>();
_container.Register<Ixxx, Data>();
_container.Register<IData, XxxData>();
container.RegisterDecorator<IData, Data1Decorator>();
_container.RegisterDecorator<IData, Data2Decorator>():
```

```
public interface Ixxx1
{
    public IEnumerable<...> x1 { get; set; }
}
public class Data1Decorator : DataDecorator
{
    public readonly Ixxx1 _xxx1; 

    public Data1Decorator(Ixxx1 xxx1, IData data) : base(data)
    {
        _xxx1 = xxx1;
    }

    public override Task Load()
    {
        return Task.WhenAll(new List<Task>() { ..., base.Load() })
        .ContinueWith((b) =>
        { 
               _xxx1.x1 = ...
        });
    }
}
```

Common storage Data

```
public interface Ixxx :
    Ixxx1,
    Ixxx2
{

}

public class Data: Ixxx
{ 
    public IEnumerable<...> x1 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<...> x2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_container.Register<Ixxx, Data>();
_container.Register<IData<Ixxx>, XxxData>();
_container.RegisterDecorator<IData<Ixxx>, Data1Decorator<Ixxx>>();
_container.RegisterDecorator<IData<Ixxx>, Data2Decorator<Ixxx>>():
```

```
    public interface IData<out TData>
    {
        TData Data { get; }
        Task Load();
    }

    public abstract class DataDecorator<TData> : IData<TData>
    {
        public readonly IData<TData> _data;

        public TData Data => _data.Data;

        protected DataDecorator(IData<TData> data) => _data = data;

        public virtual Task Load() => _data.Load();
    }
```

```
    public interface Ixxx :
        Ixxx1,
        Ixxx2
    {

    }

    public class XxxData : IData<Ixxx>
    {
        public Ixxx Data { get; }

        public XxxData(Ixxx data) => Data = data;

        public Task Load() => Task.Run(() => { });
    }
```

```
    public interface Ixxx1
    {
        public IEnumerable<...> x1 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data1Decorator<TData> : DataDecorator<TData>
        where TData : Ixxx1
    {

        public Data1Decorator(IData data) : base(data)
        {
        }

        public override Task Load()
        {
            return Task.WhenAll(new List<Task>() { ..., base.Load() })
            .ContinueWith((b) =>
            { 
                   Data.x1 = ...
            });
        }
    }
```